# how fix "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary."?

Tags: hard-drive

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA DT01ACA2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 80A94444-4AC1-4146-9094-549DB8EF6DFD

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     34 3907029134 3907029101  1.8T Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Started the server in recovery mode, tried and `fsck`. Nothing worked, in the folder `/mnt/sdb1` there is an empty folder `lost+found`, I really need to recover data.

Comment: You do have good backups? Bit unusual to see start at 34. With newer 4K drives it must be divisible by 8 or 40 would be first start sector. But normally both Windows & Linux tools use 2048 for first sector for many years. What tool did you use to partition drive? But that is not related to any issue with lost data, it is an issue with performance.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't formatted the server, that's a question for my hoster

Comment: physical sector size is 8 logical sectors, so partition is expected to start on even 8 logical sectors; 32 or 40 are closest, not 34 as you have. Now, I have hard to believe there is or will be any problem(s) caused by this.

Comment: If partition starts on physical sector boundary or not has nothing to do with data on the partition, only performance. So if you are missing data it is not because of the sector boundary. Maybe you, or some one else, has formatted the disk ? You will have to work it out and then restore your backups.